# create new array from a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [list_name] => List_Red
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [list_name] => List_Blue 
    )
)
```

...and i would like to create a new array containing only the [id]'s from it.

I would appreciate it alot if you guys could help me with that ^^

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@fabrik Your solution indeed does work but it is also incorrect as PHP will throw a E_WARNING telling you that you're appending to an array that did not yet exist. **Always** initialise your variables before you use them.

```
$newList = array();
foreach($myList as $listItem) {
    $newList[$listItem['id']] = $listItem['list_name'];
}
```

This is now a list of all your list_names in the following format.

```
Array (
    1 => List_Red
    2 => List_Blue
)
```

Much easier for you to work with and you can now iterate over it like so..

```
foreach($newList as $itemID => $itemName) {
    echo "Item ID: $itemID - Item Name: $itemName<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_map` like this:

```
$new_array = array_map( function( $a ) { return $a['id']; }, $orig_array );
```

That's assuming PHP 5.3, for PHP < 5.3 you have to use create_function:

```
$new_array = array_map( create_function( '$a', 'return $a["id"];' ), $orig_array );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $label => $data)
{
    $final[] = $data['id'];
}
```